# How to set BottomNavigationBar equal spacing between menu items?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have an android app with a BottomNavigationBar in landscape mode with four menu items. The items are bunched together in the middle like so:

[image: bunched items]

I would like to have them evenly spread across the navigation bar like this:

[image: evenly spaced items]

How do I accomplish this formatting?

Example images above come from the [material.io](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html) docs

My xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />
```

I would like my icons to be spread over the entire bar including the space annotated in red:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set this attribute for the BottomNavigationView:

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

Comment: Do you know of a solution for com.android.support:design instead of com.google.android.material? It looks like the support:design library does not include this xml attribute https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

Comment: This attribute is for `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: My understanding is that the Material Components library _exists_ to let you do what's shown in the material.io design docs. The support design library is a few generations out of date at this point.

Comment: @forpas the only xml attributes shown in the docs for `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` are `BottomNavigationView_itemBackground` 
`BottomNavigationView_itemIconTint`
`BottomNavigationView_itemTextColor`

Comment: Do you have this line in gradle: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

Comment: I was on 27.1.1 and just updated to 28.0.0 -- adding in `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` has no effect on the layout

Comment: Can you post the xml?

Comment: This is **exactly** the `BottomNavigationView` that I test and the buttons are distributed equally spaced (in landscape it's obvious).

Comment: If I remove `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"` the buttons are just like the 1st image you posted.

Comment: so the difference between indicating labeled and not is that the label shows for the item. My issue is in the spacing where they are evenly spread across the entire bar

Comment: This attribute affects this issue: *evenly spread across the entire bar*. As I mentioned in my other comments, when I remove it the buttons are all side by side in the middle. Maybe try it by code in `onCreate()`: `navigation.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);`

Comment: @forpas, ive included an annotated screenshot to show the space that it is not spread over. I see how setting the attribute as labeled spreads them some but does not spread across the entire navbar. perhaps it is not possible...

Comment: I get the result like in that image only in landscape with the emulator  of Google Nexus 9. It seems that after a certain width, the buttons don't spread any more evenly.

Comment: @forpas not working as in the ScreenShot i just tried in my emulator.

Comment: @Anmol for me everything is working fine except for landscape in large screen sizes (>9 inces).

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: this code is not working